# Dynamic graph dataset

Tags: dataset, graphs

I'm working with dynamic graph embedding but I can not seek the dataset for my problem. Can you help me find dataset with some requires:

- A series of graph which represent for dynamic graphs. Each graph in series of graph is static graph with both directed and undirected
- Label for each node (vertex) of graph to evaluate the embedding algorithm.

Thank for helping!

Answer (score 1):

I guess it is too late, so I will be short.

You may search the [SNAP graph dataset repository](https://snap.stanford.edu/data/). There, each dataset has a set of tags like *Temporal*, *Directed* or *Weighted*, for instance.

It is one of the largest such repositories, so I hope you will find what you need there.

Comment: Thank for suggesting me. I use Temporal dataset then creating (/ transform)  the dynamic graph as I needed.